# 'type' is a variable but is used like a type

Tags: c#, typecasting-operator

why is it throwing the error "'type' is a variable but is used like a type" though I am passing the type while calling the method?

```
class AsKewordImplementation 
    {
        internal object AsOperator (object obj, Type type) 
        {
            Type temp = obj.GetType ();
            if(temp==null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            while (true) 
            {
                if (type == temp) 
                {
                  obj=(type)obj;
                }
                temp = temp.BaseType;
                if (temp == null) 
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: at line "obj=(type)obj"

Comment: You are trying to typecast object type "obj" to Type "type" and assigning it back to type object, which is of no use.

Comment: type is a 'type' and they are compatible but why is it throwing error like 'type is a variable'?

Comment: If `type == temp` condition is true then your `obj` is already of type `type`. There is no meaning of casting it again.

Comment: Casting only means something if the compiler can determine the type. Since you don't know what the type than `type` represents until run-time then it cannot be used by the compiler to do any casting.